# Send a different out-of-office email to domain and non-domain senders in Google Apps Email

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

I use Google Apps at work and will be going on holiday in a couple of weeks.

I want to set up the Out-of-Office AutoReply to send a different email to people in the company and people who contact me from a different domain. Right now, the options for the autoreply are

- Only send a response to people in my Contacts
- Only send a response to people in Domain

So, is there some cleverness I can use to make two emails? One to reply to emails in the same domain, and one to reply outside?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using the Canned Responses lab combined with filters.

First, create two separate canned responses for each of the scenarios. Here's a good how-to for setting that up: http://time.com/12436/quick-gmail-trick-pre-write-email-messages-with-canned-responses/

Then you need to setup two filters:

> from:(domain.com)

And:

> from:(-domain.com), -(category:social), -(category:promotions), -(category:updates), -(category:forums)

And check the option to "Send canned response" and select the corresponding response.

[image: Create a filter]

Comment: The trouble with using a canned response, is that unlike the vacation autoresponder, the canned response will go out for every received message.

Comment: Good point @AlE. For the email outside of the domain you could use this filter: `from:(-domain.com), -(category:social), -(category:promotions), -(category:updates), -(category:forums)`

Comment: I think that Al E is pointing out that the vacation responder doesn't email the same person again and again like the canned responses do. That's the key difference. I don't want to automatically spam inboxes every time that I receive an email - just the first time.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. The only other solution I can think of would be to forward your email to separate Gmail accounts using the filters above and set up the autoresponders on those accounts. You could then setup your main account as an email address under "Send mail as" and make it the default. I imagine the autoresponders would send from that address, but I'm not positive. It's quite a lot of hassle, but it would do what you're wanting!